# Can I add a link to a tool I've made?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, ros-kinetic, docker, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I've followed information given there: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI but it doesn't provide an out-of-the-box solution.

So I decided to build a small tool to easily create and use a dockerized ROS box and I would like to share it: https://github.com/pierrekilly/docker-ros-box.

Is it worth mentioning it on the wiki page? I think that could bring some people to the project and help improving it.

Thanks!
Pierre

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290849/can-i-add-a-link-to-a-tool-i%27ve-made?/) by [Pierre Killy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35063/pierre-killy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it worth mentioning it on the wiki page?

Sure. The wiki is just that: a wiki. So it needs people like you to keep it up to date.

Just make sure you do it in such a way that it's clear that there is no 'official' way to do things, and that you're providing just one additional approach.

Register for an account, request write access and that should be it.

Thanks for making the effort to contribute, that is the only way we keep this community going.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-11**:
Related: take a look at [Singularity](https://singularity.lbl.gov/). Similar functionality to Docker, but no root permissions needed and makes things like sharing your home dir, access to GPUs/other hw etc much, much easier.

**Comment by [Pierre Killy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35063/pierre-killy/) on 2018-05-12**:
Awesome! I've updated the page: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

This is my first contribution to the ROS wiki so any feedback will be very welcome!

Thanks!